# How to send packages via bluetooth with matlab

Tags: matlab, bluetooth

I need to send send data to my PIC controller via matlab. First package of data is sent, sometimes even 3-4 packages and than it stops communication (PIC stop responding).

Eventually I would need to send 100 packages per second in the final project.

I wrote function formDataToSend to prepare 1x4 matrix of data.
First I open connection with PIC with following code:

```
b = Bluetooth('H-C-2010-06-01',1);
fopen(b);
fprintf('Connected \n')
```

When I call script with following code:

```
fwrite(b,formDataToSend(200,'Left'))
```

PIC receive this package, and if I try to send anything else PIC doesn't respond. I thought this was problem with electronic, but then I looked at pins of bluetooth module HC-05 and saw that there is no data coming to the PIC when i try any new commands with fwrite.

Function formDataToSend is:

```
function y = formDataToSend(dutyCycle,sideToTurn)
   y = 170;
    if dutyCycle > 255
       y(3) = uint8(uint16(dutyCycle)/255);
       y(2) = uint8(uint16(dutyCycle)-uint16(uint16(y(3))*256)); 
    else 
       y(3) = 0;
       y(2) = uint8(dutyCycle);
    end
    if y(2) == 255
        y(2) = 254;
    end
    if y(3) == 255
        y(3) = 254;
    end
    if strcmp('Left',sideToTurn)
       y(4) = 0;
    else 
        if strcmp('Right',sideToTurn)
          y(4) = 1;
        end
    end

end
```

Do I need to send data some other way so the bluetooth communication doesn't stop?